# How to apply using-pattern with System.Func?

Tags: c#, dispose, func

Usually I use a memory stream with the well known using pattern.

```cs
using(var mem = new MemoryStream(blob))
{
  foo(mem);
}
```

No imagine a function `bar(Func<Stream>)` defined in a client library that I have to use. I could call it like this

```cs
bar(() => new MemoryStream(blob));
```

but then nobody is disposing the stream properly. How to work around it? Should `Func` be used with `IDisposable` types at all?

Comment: Why not putting the first section of code into the Func? Just add brackets in the func body

Comment: @Aggsol What is the main purpose for this `FUNC`? Why return a stream object at all? If you need an array of bytes or a file or something to that affect you can always pass that back from your `FUNC` auX if the OP adds a using statement inside of the function, the stream will be disposed upon the call to return.

Comment: As i remember, you can call `.Dispose()` method by hand

Comment: @RyanWilson I dunno it is a client library I have to use.

Comment: Usually, the creator of an `IDisposable` is the owner, so the one who creates an object is responsible for disposing of it. So, the `bar` method should dispose it. However, it's unclear whether the `Func<Stream>` will create an object or will just provide an existing instance. In that case, the class that provides the `Func<Stream>` should dispose of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a poorly designed library.

If you know for a fact that the library **does not dispose of the stream** and **it doesn't hold the `Func<Stream>` for later use**, then you can do this:

```
using(var mem = new MemoryStream(blob))
{
    bar(() => mem);
}
```